# Error bar not showing all the values in mschart

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I am using VB.NET with mschart. I am using ErroBar chartype but i am not able to label all the values (medium, upper and lower). When i set `chart.Series("ErrorBar").IsValueShownAsLabel = True`, only upper value is shown.
[image]

I want to show the center, upper and lower values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look on this may help [Simple Chart with ToolTip using ASP.NET Chart Control](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/465155/simple-chart-with-tooltip-using-asp-net-chart-cont) [ErrorBarChart.cs - referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.DataVisualization/Common/ChartTypes/ErrorBarChart.cs)

Comment: Thanks Wojciech Wojtulewski for your quick response!  find a very usefule reference you gave me, but i found the code a bit complex for what i wanted, so i decided to write a simple solution using annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution adopted by me was a simpler one using annotations as can be seen in the code below

```
    Dim Media1 As New RectangleAnnotation()
    Media1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Media1.Text = FormatNumber(D20, 4)
    Dim point As PointF = New PointF(chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ValueToPosition(1), chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ValueToPosition(D20))
    Media1.AnchorX = point.X + 10
    Media1.AnchorY = point.Y + 2
    Media1.AllowMoving = True

    Dim L1 As New RectangleAnnotation()
    L1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    L1.Text = FormatNumber(D20 - result * My.Settings("IncertezaDensidade20") / 2, 4)
    point = New PointF(chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ValueToPosition(1), chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ValueToPosition(D20 - result * My.Settings("IncertezaDensidade20") / 2))
    L1.AnchorX = point.X
    L1.AnchorY = point.Y + 10
    L1.AllowMoving = True

    Dim L2 As New RectangleAnnotation()
    L2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    L2.Text = FormatNumber(D20 + result * My.Settings("IncertezaDensidade20") / 2, 4)
    point = New PointF(chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ValueToPosition(1), chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ValueToPosition(D20 + result * My.Settings("IncertezaDensidade20") / 2))
    L2.AnchorX = point.X
    L2.AnchorY = point.Y - 5
    L2.AllowMoving = True
```

The chart now, can be seen below

[image]